# Identify sot-23 smd component and possible replacement

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, datasheet, surface-mount

I need help identifying this rusty smd component (sot-23 3 pins).
It comes from an early 90's sony discman.

Thank you!

[image: Rusty component]

Comment: Can you measure any (body) diodes inside it with a multimeter? If yes, what polarity/pinout do you get? This should narrow down the searches.

Comment: Hi @winny. There's around 0.7v between lower left and right pin. Also similar voltage between lower left and top pin. 0v between right and top pin. Values measures with a multimeter (diode mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SANYO 2SD1048. 
http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/2/S/B/8/2SB815.shtml

It’s an PNP “audio” transistor. 20 V and 0.7 A rated.

Given the 0.7 A rating which is a bit more than small signal standard, was it located close to the speaker/headphones output?

X denotes 2SD1048. 
7 denotes a hFE between 300 and 600.

You can most probably replace it with any PNP with similar hFE and current capability.

[image]

Comment: Great!. Thank you @winny.

Comment: @perplex_bcn You are welcome! Feel free to accept my answer when you have verified it was correct.